# Is it possible to force task bar on top (on Win7)?

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar

Is it possible to move the task bar on top; I currently have a window that takes the whole screen hiding the task bar and I'd need it to pop up on top again. It would be ok to do this programmatically but my research so far points to that not being possible (e.g. SetWindowPos(hwndTaskBar, HWND_TOPMOST, ...) does not seem to work.

Comment: Can't you `BringWindowToTop(hwndTaskBar)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task bar already has the TOPMOST property, so I suspect setting it again doesn't do anything.

According to [this post from Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/21/495246.aspx) you can use `HWND_TOP` to move the window to the top in all cases.